# how can I Add a ABRecordRef to a NSMutableArray in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray, addressbook

I want to create an array of ABRecordRef(s) to store contacts which have a valid birthday field.

```
   NSMutableArray* bContacts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
   CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
   CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);

   for( int i = 0 ; i < nPeople ; i++ )
   {
       ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, i );
       NSDate* birthdayDate = (NSDate*) ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonBirthdayProperty);
       if (birthdayDate != nil){
           [bContacts addObject:ref];
       }
   }
```

The compiler shows this warning:
**warning: passing argument 1 of 'addObject:' discards qualifiers from pointer target type**
I searched the web and found I have to cast ABRecordRef to a ABRecord* to be able to store in a NSMutableArray.

```
[bContacts addObject:(ABRecord*) ref];
```

But it seems ABRecord is not part of iOS frameworks. Now how I store ABRecordRef to NSMutableArray?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
[bContacts addObject:(id) ref];
```

Answer (score 12):

A `ABRecordRef` is a typedef for `CFTypeRef` and that in turn resolves to `const void *`. And this is where the warning comes from: with the call to `addObject:`, the `const` qualifier is "lost".

In this case we know it's OK. A CFTypeRef is a semi-highlevel type, instances of this type support `CFRetain` and `CFRelease`. That in turn means it's probably OK to cast it to `id` and treat it as a NSObject. So you should be simply able to do:

```
[bContacts addObject:(id)ref];
```

Answer (score 6):

Create an NSObject wich store your ABRecordRef like this :

```
// ABContact.h
@interface ABContact : NSObject
{
    ABRecordRef _record;
}

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSDate *birthday;

- (id)initWithRecord:(ABRecordRef)aRecord;

@end

// ABContact.m
@implementation ABContact

#pragma mark - Init

- (id)initWithRecord:(ABRecordRef)aRecord;
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
        _record = CFRetain(aRecord);
    return self;
}


#pragma mark - Getter

- (NSDate *)birthday
{
    return (NSDate *)ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonBirthdayProperty) autorelease];
}


#pragma mark - Memory management

- (void)dealloc
{
    CFRelease(_record);
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

You should take a look at the Erica Sadum library the author of the iPhone cookbook. Here is the code wich inspire this code -> [url](https://github.com/erica/iphone-3.0-cookbook-/tree/master/C18-Address%20Book/02-Display%20Contact)

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but since the **introduction of ARC**, this is handled in a different way.

There are two possible ways of adding an `ABRecordRef` to an `NSMutableArray` now, both of which require a bridged cast:

**Direct conversion**

```
[bContacts addObject:(__bridge id)(ref)];
```

This simply converts the `ABRecordRef` pointer, and should be used, if you didn't create `ref` yourself using a method that has `Create` in its name.

**Transfer ownership to ARC**

```
[bContacts addObject:CFBridgingRelease(ref)];
```

This converts the `ABRecordRef` pointer, and in addition transfers its ownership to ARC. This should be used, if you used e.g. `ABPersonCreate()` to create a new person.

More information can be found in the [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html). There are also many other informative sources here on Stack Overflow, such as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18067108/1770453).