# when should you use __bridge vs. CFBridgingRelease/CFBridgingRetain?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-graphics, automatic-ref-counting

I have this code that uses "__bridge" to cast the ids of colors:

```
  CGColorRef tabColor = (5 == 5
                         ? [UIColor blueColor].CGColor
                         : [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);

  CGColorRef startColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
  CGColorRef endColor   = tabColor;
  NSArray    *colors    = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(__bridge id)startColor, (__bridge id)endColor, nil];

  CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, (__bridge CFArrayRef)colors, locations);
```

but would:

```
  NSArray    *colors    = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)CFBridgingRelease(startColor), (id)CFBridgingRelease(endColor), nil];

  CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, (CFArrayRef)CFBridgingRetain(colors), locations);
```

be a better solution?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You don't "own" the Core Foundation objects `startColor`, `endColor` because they were
not returned by a function that has "Create" or "Copy" in its name (compare ["The Create Rule"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html) in the "Memory Management Programming Guide for Core Foundation".
And because you don't own the objects, you must not "transfer the ownership" to ARC with
`CFBridgingRelease()`. So

```
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:(__bridge id)startColor, (__bridge id)endColor, nil];
```

is correct. And

```
CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, (__bridge CFArrayRef)colors, locations);
```

is also correct because

```
CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, (CFArrayRef)CFBridgingRetain(colors), locations);
```

would pass a (+1) retained array to `CGGradientCreateWithColors()`. This would be a memory
leak because that function does not release the `colors` argument.

Answer (score 0):

With NSURL is the same problem

```
NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound" ofType:@"wav"];
NSURL *soundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(CFBridgingRetain(soundURL), &soundEffect);
```