# ERROR objc_retainedObject() unavailable

Tags: objective-c, xcode

when i'm trying to build my project I have a new error where `objc_retainedObject()` is used.

I have the error message `objc_retianedObject is unavailable: use CFBridgingRelease() or a (__bridge_transfer id) cast instead`.

I replaced the usages of `objc_retainedObject()` by `CFBridgingRelease` and there are no longer errors and I can run the app, but when the app is going to display my QRCode-scanning view, it crashed without messages.

It is the same when I put `#define objc_retainedObject(o) ((__bridge_transfer id)(objc_objectptr_t)(o))` which was supposed to be a solution.
I believe that it is an XCode configuration or a missing library problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Do not recreate `objc_retainedObject`. It was removed on purpose. `CFBridgingRelease` and `CFBridgingRetain` are the correct tools for moving CF objects into ARC. (`__bridge` is the tool for dealing with CF objects that you don't need to transfer to ARC because you aren't storing them.)

If your program is crashing, you're probably managing memory incorrectly. It is likely that `objc_retainedObject` was incorrect (even if you happened to get away with it). See [when should you use __bridge vs. CFBridgingRelease/CFBridgingRetain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067108/when-should-you-use-bridge-vs-cfbridgingrelease-cfbridgingretain) for correct memory management when transferring CF objects to ARC.

Without knowing more about the code, I can't guess exactly where you've made a mistake, but you probably are calling `CFBridgingRelease` on an object that you didn't acquire via the [Create Rule](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html). You don't just throw `CFBridgingRelease` on every CF object you encounter. You need to make sure you're balancing an existing retain.